# R How can I use a previous value from the column I am creating

Tags: r, lag

I would like to how to use a previous value from the row I want to create. In excel it is easy but can't get it right in R.

I have the following data

```
data

d               
6.081371                
7.527626                
30.669937               
5.402242                
37.664694   

#coefficients
w <- tan(pi*(0.5/0.802)/10)
k1 <- 2^0.5*w
k2 <- w^2
a0 <- k2/(1+k1+k2)
k3 <- 2*a0/k2
a1 <- 2*a0
b1 <- -2*a0+k3
b2 <- 1-2*a0-k3
```

I want to create a new column (g) with the following formula:

```
data$g <– a0*d+a1*(previous value of d)+a0*(value 2 positions above of d)+b1*(previous value of calculated new column g)+b2*(value 2 positions above of new column g)
```

I am able to calculate the first part with lag, but can't use the previous values of the created column
Data is longer than 20000 observations so I don't know if a loop would be a good option.

Thanks!

Comment: `d <- 11:17`, "previous value of d": `c(NA, head(d, -1))`, "value 2 positions above of d": `c(NA, NA, head(d, -2))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inititalise a data$g column first:

```
data$g <- 0
```

Then:

**Changed below to a for loop:**

```
for i in 3:nrow(data){
   data$g[i] = a0*data$d[i]*a1*data$d[i-1]+ao*data$d[i-2]+b1*data$g[i-1]+b2*data$g[i-2]
}
```

The main problem I can see for this is that it won't calculate the first two rows of g.

**old response**

`data$g <– a0*d+a1*lag(data$d)+a0*lag(data$d, 2)+b1*lag(data$g)+b2*lag(data$g, 2)`

Comment: I get the hole column with NA

Comment: Did you run the data$g <- NA before the other code?

Comment: Yes, if I run the hole line I get the NA. If I separate It I get the calculation but a wrong one. Thanks for the responses!

Comment: Ahh, that sucks, sorry. Just one more thing. Does it calculate what you want if you set `data$g <- 0`?

Comment: running data$g<- 0 made the hole line work, but it seems it only calculates the first row correctly, I wanted to calculate it for every row... Thanks anyway

Comment: I've tried to update the answer to try with a for loop, starting from the third row (because that's the first row you can look at values from two rows higher). I hope this might help you until a better answer comes along.

Comment: Thank and sorry again but I am new with for loops and can't make the code run. Changed the = for <- but shows df1 as missing argument, and if I change the "df"  for "data" it collapses. The first two rows of g not being calculated is not a problem for what I am looking for

Comment: I'd missed off an index for the first ```data$g```. Hopefully, it will work if you try again.

Comment: That's great! Glad it worked and sorry it took so long to get there!

Answer (score -1):

Think you're best of for-looping it if the lag function is causing issues- 20,000 rows should be pretty speedy!

Comment: Any idea of how to use a for-loop in the specific code? I have no experience using for loops...

Comment: will write one up tomorrow - once my dissertation is handed in :)